# Java function charAt

Tags: java, function, charat

Can anyone tell me what this snippet of code does? In my understanding it returns the sum of the indexes in the string, for example, in string is `"Hello"` it would return 10? AM I wrong here, please let me know…

```
public String decrString(final String s) {
    final char[] value = new char[s.length()];
    for (char index = '\0'; index < s.length(); ++index) {
        value[index] = s.charAt(index);
        if (index % '\u0002' == 0) {
            value[index] -= index;
        }
        else {
            value[index] += index;
        }
    }
    return new String(value);
}
```

I googled `charAt` - it simply returns the current index. Java isn't my strongest, first time seeing Java code.

Comment: Looks like a cipher that offsets every odd character by `index` and every even character by `-index`.

Comment: This is a little absurd. They're going from 0 to the length of the string iterating by 1. If they're on an even index, then they subtract the index value from the value of the existing character, if they're at an odd index value then they add that value. Maybe it is some sort of "encryption"?

Comment: "it simply returns the current index." charAt returns the value of the character as a unicode point. eg. `String s = "cat";` then `s.charAt(0);` returns `'c'`.

Comment: No one is stopping you from copy-pasting the code in a simple java program and calling it right? You can even debug and check the outcome realtime. :)

Answer (score 1):

this is kind of [Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography) function and changes a string to an encoded String.([ciphertext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext)).

##### How it Work?

let's look at some input and output

```
System.out.println(decrString("AAAAAAAAAAAA"));

AB?D=F;H9J7L
```

---

```
System.out.println(decrString("111111111111"));

12/4-6+8):'<
```

---

```
System.out.println(decrString("999999999"));

9:7<5>3@1
```

---

```
System.out.println(decrString("55555"));

56381
```

it starts from first of String and if it place is odd it adds [place index] and if it place is even is mines [place index]

look at first example you can see `AB D F H J L` it generated with this formula `(A-0=A)(A+1=B)(A+3=D)(A+5=F)(A+7=H)...`

look at third example you can find this `9 7 5 3 1` it generated such this
`(9-0=0)(9-2=7)(9-4=5)(9-6=3)(9-8=1)`

look at forth example it is `56381` and generated like this
`(5-0=5)(5+1=6)(5-2=3)(5+3=8)(5-4=1)`